# GHA composite actions substitute in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to migrate my ci configuration from github actions to azure devops pipeline. There is a feature of using composite actions in github actions which merges multiple calls to a particular action into one. Do we have something similar to this in azure devops?

For example in my pipeline task, I have a step to initialise and then various other steps follow. When I mention this task multiple times in my pipeline, I want the initialise to sep to run only once.

TIA

Tried reading the documentation but couldn't find anything. Also tried searching on community but didn't got any useful results.

Comment: can you show an example in GHA yaml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe directly equivalent functionality exists in azure pipelines. Composing and re-using elements is done using [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).

Repeated calls to the same template will still result in the template action being called more than once, but breaking up the functionality of your different actions into multiple templates will allow you to compose a pipeline where the initialization runs just once at the start.

Alternatively you can set a [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) the first time you run the intialization task (paying attention to the scope and using an output variable if appropriate) and then check the value of the variable later to decide whether to re-run the initialization task perhaps using [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages)